# LSTM calculation with Vanilla Numpy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I've compared LSTM result with Keras/Tensorflow calculation and Numpy calculation. However, the result is slightly different:

```
Numpy: [[ 0.16315128 -0.04277606 0.26504123 0.08014129 0.38561829]]
Keras: [[ 0.16836338 -0.04930305 0.25080156 0.08938988 0.3537751 ]]
```

Keras' LSTM implementation does not use `tf.contrib.rnn` but Keras directly manages the parameters, and `tf.matmul` is used to calculate. I found the corresponding implementation of Keras and tried the same calculation with Numpy, but the values are slightly different as shown above.

I have checked the formula several times and it seems like the same. The only difference is the differences between `tf.matmul` or `np.dot`. Maybe there are some differences about decimal point calculation method. Even so, I think the results are too much different. The biggest difference is about 10%. I'd like to match the Numpy calculation with the tensorflow calculation. If someone could give me some hint or point me to the right implementation, I'd really appreciate it.

Keras implementation and the Numpy code implemented myself:

- Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1921-L1948
- Numpy: https://github.com/likejazz/jupyter-notebooks/blob/master/deep-learning/lstm-keras-inspect.py

Comment: If you run either of these implementations multiple times I would expect you to get different answers on each run due to random initialization. Try it out for each model and see what is typical variance from one run to the next. My guess is that these numbers will look perfectly reasonable in that context.

Comment: @DavidParks You are right. But I get slightly different results each other every time and that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of `recurrent_activation` is `'hard_sigmoid'` for Keras `LSTM` layer. However, the original sigmoid function is used in your NumPy implementation.

So you can either change the `recurrent_activation` argument to `'sigmoid'`,

```py
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(8, 3), recurrent_activation='sigmoid'))
```

or use the "hard" sigmoid function in your NumPy code.

```py
def hard_sigmoid(x):
    return np.clip(0.2 * x + 0.5, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Great! I found that the initial value of recurrent_activation is `hard_sigmoid` in Keras implementations. I was able to solve the problem. Thank you.